# Understanding the `include` statement behavior for "subsequent" mixin modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include

I am trying to understand the `include` statement behavior when used in multiple Mixins. That is, I have these statements:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DoubleIncludedModule
  include AModule

  # ...
end

module AModule
  include DoubleIncludedModule

  # ...
end

module DoubleIncludedModule
  # ...
end
```

How many times will be the `DoubleIncludedModule` included in the `Article` class? That is, since the "subsequent" inclusion of the `DoubleIncludedModule` (first in the `Article` class and then in `AModule` included by the `Article` class itself), will be the "double inclusion" issue automatically handled by Ruby or will the `DoubleIncludedModule` (wrongly) included two times?

Of course, I would like to include the `DoubleIncludedModule` module *only one time*. How can I make that (maybe by using some Ruby on Rails methods) the proper way?

Comment: Just because you're using Rails doesn't mean the question has anything to do with Rails. Rails doesn't change how `include` works at all. This is purely a Ruby question.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - It could be that exist some Ruby on Rails methods that can help to solve some issues as-like that in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll answer with an example:

```
module A
  def self.included base
    puts "A included in #{base}"
  end
end

module B
  include A

  def self.included base
    puts "B included in #{base}"
  end
end

class C
  include A
  include B
end

p C.ancestors
```

prints

```
A included in B
A included in C
B included in C
[C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As we can see, `A` is included only once into `C`. Though *technically* it was included twice since it was included into `B` which was also included into `C`. Does this matter? Probably not. Each still only occurs once in the ancestor chain, and any methods would've been overridden with equivalent implementations—i.e., essentially a no-op. Unless you're doing something exotic with the `included` hook, you're unlikely to notice anything.